# Account and Test Account Interest class

Tags: java, oop

I would like someones expert opinion on both of my account class and the test account interest class. The issue I am facing is that the code from the test account interest class just multiplies on from the previous 12 month compute interest when it is supposed to be used only once.

The issue is in the

```
public double computeInterest(int n)
        {
            balance=balance*(Math.pow((1+rate),n/12)); 
            return balance;
        }
```

It is in this method of where the problem is that I should not use the balance but to use a variable that will store the answer but I did not understand the person that very clearly and he was very vague by only stating a variable should be used.

```
public class Account
{
    private double balance; //STATE
    private double interestRate; //STATE
    private double rate;//STATE

    public Account()
    {
        balance = 0; 
        interestRate = 0;
    }

    public Account(double amount, double interestRate)
    {
        balance = amount;   
        rate = interestRate;

    } 

    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance=balance+amount;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }

    public void setInterest(double rate)
    {
        balance = balance + balance * rate;
        //this.setInterst = setInterest;  
        //setInterest = InterestRate / 12;
    }

   public double computeInterest(int n)
    {
        balance=balance*(Math.pow((1+rate),n/12)); 
        return balance;
    }

    public double getsetInterest()
    {
        return rate;
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        balance =0;
    }

}
```

This is my test account interest class:

```
public class TestAccountInterest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Account acc1 = new Account(100, 0.1);//0.10);
        Account acc2 = new Account(133, 0.2); //0.20);

      /*************************************
       ACC1 ACCOUNT BELOW
       *************************************/
        //acc1.deposit(100);
        //acc1.withdraw(100);
        System.out.println(acc1.computeInterest(12));
//      //acc1.computeInterest(12);
//      System.out.println(acc1.computeInterest(24));

        /**************************************
        ACC2 ACCOUNT BELOW
         **************************************/
        acc2.withdraw(100);
        acc2.deposit(100);
        //acc2.computeInterest(24);
        System.out.println(acc2.computeInterest(24));

    }

}
```

This is the final output:

```
110.00000000000001
191.51999999999998
```

As you can see for the second one the figure is multiplied by the 12 month compute interest with the 24 month compute interest this stems from the method in the account class:

```
 public double computeInterest(int n)
        {
            balance=balance*(Math.pow((1+rate),n/12)); 
            return balance;
        }
```

If I take out the balance it still causes and error so I confused on this particular part.

Comment: `computeInterest` should do just that: compute the interest. Not update *other* state. Or return the balance. It should return the *interest*.

Comment: It does return the interest in the (1+rate) part but I was told the first part of balance should be removed

Comment: It does *not* return the interest. It returns the balance. And *sets* the balance, which is counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Code,

```
public double computeInterest(int n) {
  balance = balance * (Math.pow((1 + rate), n / 12)); 
  return balance;
}
```

should be changed to

```
public double computeInterest(int n) {
  return balance * Math.pow(1 + rate, n / 12);
}
```

You shouldn't change `balance` field while computing interest. You might like to have a separate method to update `balance` where you do , `balance = balance + computed_interest` or something like that.

Also, I have remove unnecessary parenthesis. That was not an error but simply making your code less readable.